# How to use qmlRegisterType to set custom properties from C++ into QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm currently setting the content of CustomList from C++ into QML by using setContextProperty. The following code works fine, but if there were multiple lists, I would have to create a CustomList and ViewModel for each of them and expose them with setContextProperty using different names.

The CustomList inherits from QAbstractListModel and contains only strings for simplicity reasons.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    CustomListModel list1;
    std::vector<QString> v {"Step #1", "Step #2", "Step #3"};
    list1.InsertItems(v);
    CustomListModel list2;
    std::vector<QString> v2 {"Step #11", "Step #22", "Step #33"};
    list2.InsertItems(v2);

    ViewModel _view;
    _view.setListModel(&list1);
    ViewModel _view2;
    _view2.setListModel(&list2);

    QQuickView view;
    QQmlContext *context = view.engine()->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("_view", &_view);
    context->setContextProperty("_view2", &_view2);
    context->setContextProperty("_listModel", &list1);
    context->setContextProperty("_listModel2", &list2);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}


class ViewModel: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(CustomListModel *list READ getListModel WRITE setListModel NOTIFY listChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int index READ getIndex WRITE setIndex NOTIFY indexChanged)

public:
    ViewModel(): mListModel(nullptr) { }

    CustomListModel *getListModel() const {
        return mListModel;
    }
    void setListModel(CustomListModel* model) {
        mListModel = model;
        emit listChanged();
    }
    int getIndex() const {
        return mIndex;
    }
    void setIndex(int newIndex) {
        mIndex = newIndex;
        emit indexChanged();
    }

signals:
    void listChanged();
    void indexChanged();

private:
    CustomListModel *mListModel;
    int mIndex{0};
};


// main.qml
Column {
  width: 400
  height: 400

  CustomPage { }
  OtherPage { }
}

// CustomPage.qml
Item {
   height: childrenRect.height + myText.height
   width: 100
   Text {
       id: myText
       text: "Index " + _view.index
       MouseArea {
          anchors.fill: parent
          onClicked: {
             _view.index++
          }
       }
  }
    
   MyList {
       id: list
       anchors.top: myText.bottom
       model: _listModel
   }
}

// OtherPage.qml
Item {
   height: childrenRect.height
   width: 100
   Text {
      id: myText
      text: "Index " + _view2.index
      MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: {
             _view2.index++
          }
       }
   }
    
   MyList {
      id: list
      anchors.top: myText.bottom
      model: _listModel2
   }
}
    
//MyList.qml
ListView {
    id: myList
    width: 300
    height: 200
    
    delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            color: "blue"
    
            Text {
                text: model.message
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe using qmlRegisterType for the ViewModel and set the CustomList property directly? Then I would only have to create one new CustomListModel for each page.

I'm having trouble using qmlRegisterType. I tried the following but it returned an undefined model:

```
// main.cpp
qmlRegisterType<ViewModel>("ViewModel", 1, 0, "ViewModel");
qmlRegisterType<CustomListModel>();

// CustomPage.qml
MyList {
  model: ViewModel {
     list: _listModel
   }
}
```

Is this even the right approach or should I stick to setting a bunch of context properties?

***** **Update** *****

I managed to display the custom list property. My question remains: Is there a way to dynamically set the list property from C++?

```
// CustomPage.qml 
Item {

  ViewModel {
    id: view
    list: _listModel // or _listModel2. How to customize?
  }

  height: childrenRect.height + myText.height
  width: 100
  Text {
    id: myText
    text: "Index " + view.index
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            view.index++
        }
    }
  }

  MyList {
    id: list
    anchors.top: myText.bottom
    model: view.list
  }
}
```

Comment: You're showing some code, but you haven't described what the problem is with your code. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. The code works fine, but I'm trying to use qmlRegisterType instead of calling setContextProperty and I don't know how to set the list up correctly.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the right thing with ViewModel. But if you use qmlRegisterType with CustomListModel, then you have to create the instance of your model from QML. Is that what you want? Or do you still want to instantiate the model from C++? I think you should still use setContextProperty with your CustomListModels.

Comment: So you think it's the better approach to set a context property for each ViewModel/CustomList pair? The ViewModel is kind of a wrapper and I was hoping that there was a way to set CustomList in C++ and have one ViewModel definition where I set the list property for each of them

Comment: No, I was suggesting using qmlRegisterType with ViewModel, but use setContextProperty with each CustomList.